# django send_mail отправка писем от любого адресата

Tags: python, django, sendmail, django-cms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно отправлять письма от любого адресата?
У меня в .settings.py прописаны следующие настройки

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.yandex.ru'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'yandexUser'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'secretPassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Далее в shell следующий код **работает**

`send_mail('Django mail', 'This e-mail was send with Django.', 'yandexUser@ya.ru', ['mySecondMail@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)`

А вот так уже не работает

`send_mail('Django mail', 'This e-mail was send with Django.', 'info@any-site.ru', ['mySecondMail@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)`

На php у меня с этим проблем нет, я так же использую в качестве почтового сервера Yandex или Google, а в качестве адресата подставляю любой адрес.

---

получилось сделать вот так:

```
import smtplib

def sendMail(email_from, email_to, subject, text):
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.yandex.ru", 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login("myYandexAccount", "o_MyPassword")
    message = "\r\n".join([ \
        "From: {}".format(email_from), \
        "To: {}".format(email_to), \
        "Subject: {}".format(subject), \
        "", \
        "{}".format(text) \
        ])
    server.sendmail("myYandexAccount@ya.ru", email_to, message)
    server.quit()

sendMail(
    'email_from@gmail.com',
    'email_to@gmail.com',
    'subject message',
    'body text here...'
)
```

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Ошибку какую выдаёт?

Comment: `send_mail('Django mail', 'This e-mail was send with Django.', 'test@gmail.com', ['myemail@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)`

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
 ...
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (553, b'5.7.1 Sender address rejected: not owned by auth user.', 'test@gmail.com')`

Comment: Ошибки в коде нет. Сервер отвечает, что не примет письмо, так как пользователь, через которого осуществлялась авторизация, не владеет адресом, с которого делается попытка отправки.

Comment: Так я и понял. А есть ли какая то возможность на Django отправлять письма от любого адресата? На моем php сайте с этим вообще проблем нет. Я так же использую учетку в Яндексе, и в поле "отправитель" указываю любой адрес, и все прекрасно работает.

Comment: Это очень удобно, когда я использую форму обратной связи, человек заполняет поле для email и пишет свой вопрос. Сайт отправляет мне письмо и в поле "отправитель" подставляет email из формы.

Comment: Не помещайте информацию необходимую для ответа в комментарии, отредактируйте ваш вопрос вместо этого. Нажмите [edit] и добавьте traceback в вопрос. Не помещайте решение (ответ) в вопрос, [опубликуйте как свой ответ.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного покопавшись в исходниках нашел решение

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
msg = EmailMessage(
  subject=u'Тема письма',
  body=u'тело сообщения тут',
  from_email='yandexUser@ya.ru',
  to=('email_to@gmail.com',),
  headers={'From': 'email_from@me.com'}
)
msg.content_subtype = 'html'
msg.send()
```